# Dynamically/Conditionally adding multiple LINQ GroupBy

Tags: linq, dynamic, group-by, conditional-statements

I have a user interface that offers user selection of

1. Table Type (choice between two tables of almost identical column set)
2. Columns
3. Operation (sum, mean, median etc.)
4. GroupBy options (a bunch of check boxes)

I am planning to create a method that returns resultset based on the user selections, and while I think I am through with everything else (apart from table selection), I am stuck on how to use GroupBy (or any other way) to build up the group by clauses one after the another.

This is the only thing that is now making me thinking of going back to using a simple SQL string generation to do this.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
public IQueryable<ACSImpactAnalysisModel> GetDataForReport(TableType table, uint year,     OpType operation, uint groupOptions, uint measures)
    {
        var dataContext = new ACSImpactEntities();

        var discharges = from p in dataContext.ACSNationals
                         select new 
                         {
                             p.YEAR,
                             p.AGE,
                             p.FEMALE,
                             p.RACE,
                             p.ASOURCE,
                             p.PAY1,
                             LOS = p.LOS > 0 ? p.LOS : 0,
                             CHG = p.TOTCHG > 0 ? p.TOTCHG : 0,
                             NPR = p.NPR > 0 ? p.NPR : 0,
                             DIS_STS = p.DISPUB04 > 0 ? p.DISPUB04 : 0
                         };

        //if (table == TableType.states)
        //    discharges = from p in dataContext.ACSStates
        //                 select p;


        List<int> years = new List<int>();
        if ((year & Constants.YEAR2008) == Constants.YEAR2008) years.Add(2008);
        if ((year & Constants.YEAR2009) == Constants.YEAR2009) years.Add(2009);

        discharges = discharges.Where(a => years.Any(b => a.YEAR == b));

        if ((groupOptions & Constants.SEX) == Constants.SEX)
            discharges = discharges.Where(a => a.FEMALE > 0);

        if ((groupOptions & Constants.RACE) == Constants.RACE)
            discharges = discharges.Where(a => a.RACE > 0);

        if ((groupOptions & Constants.ER_ADMISSION) == Constants.ER_ADMISSION)
            discharges = discharges.Where(a => a.ASOURCE > 0);

        if ((groupOptions & Constants.PAYER_TYPE) == Constants.PAYER_TYPE)
            discharges = discharges.Where(a => a.PAY1 > 0);

        var analysis = from a in discharges
                       select new
                       {
                           AGE_GROUP = 
                           (
                                a.AGE >= 18 && a.AGE <= 44 ? "18-44" :
                                a.AGE >= 45 && a.AGE <= 54 ? "45-54" :
                                a.AGE >= 55 && a.AGE <= 64 ? "55-64" : ">= 65"
                           ),
                           SEX = (a.FEMALE == 1 ? "FEMALE" : "MALE"),
                           RACE = 
                           (
                                a.RACE == 1 ? "WHITE" :
                                a.RACE == 2 ? "BLACK" :
                                a.RACE == 3 ? "HISPANIC" :
                                a.RACE == 4 ? "ASIAN OR PACIFIC ISLANDER" :
                                a.RACE == 5 ? "NATIVE AMERICAN" :
                                a.RACE == 6 ? "OTHER" : ""
                           ),
                           ASOURCE = (a.ASOURCE == 1 ? "ER" : "NON ER"),
                           PAY1 =
                           (
                                a.PAY1 == 1 ? "MEDICARE" :
                                a.PAY1 == 2 ? "MEDICAID" :
                                a.PAY1 == 3 ? "PRIVATE INCLUDE HMO" :
                                a.PAY1 == 4 ? "SELF PAY" :
                                a.PAY1 == 5 ? "NO CHARGE" :
                                a.PAY1 == 6 ? "OTHER" : ""
                           ),
                            a.YEAR,
                            a.FEMALE,
                            a.LOS,
                            a.CHG,
                            a.NPR,
                            a.DIS_STS
                       };

        var grouped_analysis = analysis.GroupBy(groups => groups.YEAR);

        //These lines generate error, but this is something what I want to be able to  do
        if ((groupOptions & Constants.AGE_GROUP) == Constants.AGE_GROUP)
            grouped_analysis = analysis.GroupBy(age_group => age_group.AGE_GROUP);

        if ((groupOptions & Constants.ASOURCE) == Constants.ASOURCE)
            grouped_analysis = analysis.GroupBy(asource => asource.ASOURCE);


        return analysis;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) and you might need also [Predicate Builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).

Comment: Regarding Dynamic Linq, wouldn't it defeat the whole purpose of writing type safe query?  As for Predicate Builder I couldn't understand how it would be helpful in getting multiple conditional group-bys added to the resultset.  It seems more suitable building dynamic where/filter clauses

Comment: Is good to know about Predicate Builder when dealing with this kind of queries ( and yes, is for Where)

Comment: DynamicLinq has an extension method for group by. I saw samples here on SO.

Comment: Hmmm... I guess Dynamic Linq is the next best thing.  Ideally I would like to have multiple GroupBy calls (conditional) one after another, just like I had done with the conditional where clauses.  I will sleep on it and try to find more options before going with Dynamic Linq and your solution.  Thanks.

Comment: After spending a lot of time on finding a proper documentation of Linq Dynamic Query Library I find it hard to work with it and it does not even provide any significant benefit over using string based query generation, I might have to go back to using latter.  However, thanks for pointing me whatever alternate there was available.

Comment: In the download found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb894665.aspx, there is a folder DynamicQuery and a document DynamicExpressions.html.